# php55w-common conflict when adding php-fpm

Tags: nginx, php

So I am trying to add php-fpm to have it work with nginx. But the issue I am having is I already have some other php stuff in there like php-common and now it's having conflicts. So centOS is suggesting I use `--skip-broken` but i'm not sure if that's the best way to go? Would there be any issues if I do end up using that to install php-fpm?

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: dallas.tx.mirror.xygenhosting.com
 * epel: www.gtlib.gatech.edu
 * extras: mirror.millry.co
 * updates: mirror.cs.vt.edu
 * webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-fpm.x86_64 0:5.3.3-27.el6_5.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-27.el6_5.1 for package: php-fpm-5.3.3-27.el6_5.1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.3.3-27.el6_5.1 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: php55w-common-5.5.16-1.w6.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 5.5.0
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php55w-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.1.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: You mostly likely should be looking to install `php55w-fpm.x86_64`

Answer (score 0):

If you know what you are doing, you can upgrade PHP by:

```
yum install yum-plugin-replace
yum replace php-common --replace-with=php55w-common
```

It will likely give you a message “WARNING: Unable to resolve all providers …”. This is normal, and you can continue by tying “y“. You will be given a chance to see what packages will be installed and removed before again being given a chance to confirm.

Then you can continue with your previous installation command

Comment: `php55w-common` looks to be installed already. `php-common` is trying to be installed (as a dependency of `php-fpm`), resulting in the conflict

Comment: You can try to install php55w-fpm

Comment: This worked for me. After installing `php55w-fpm` I just had to `start` and `enable`  the `php-fpm` service.